# how to change "SHOP NOW" caption in banner slider?

Tags: banner-slider

i use "manage banners" in the "plazathemes". it has a "url" option and i get **shop now** caption for the link automatically.
[image]

[image]

[image]

how can I rename **Shop Now** caption ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not use plazathemes but all theme banner slider create the blocks.

I am not sure but try this may be help you.

So you goes to the admin panel.

Open the `Content > Blocks > and find the your banner slider blocks`.

You find the block and change "Shop Now" button links.